# How to sync iPhone photo albums to iPhoto

Tags: iphone, photos.app

I'm using iPhone4 and the latest iOS. I've created albums and categorized my photos into the albums.

Question is, how can I then sync the photos WITH the albums into iPhoto?

Comment: This question has come up before, unfortunately there isn't a way to do this currently.

Answer (score 2):

That is a good question! The answer, as far as I can tell, is: You can't!

The whole system of syncing the Photos app and iPhoto among your devices, and between each other, seems to be a work in progress. I could go on about all the issues, but the short answer is, you can't do it right now.